# Reemplazar un carácter en especifico de un STRING

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buenas noches Titanes de la programación, tengo un problema, como puse en el titulo quiero reemplazar un carácter en especifico de un string, por ejemplo:

```
               JS                                        PHP
var elstring = '1011000001100000';      |    $elstring = '1011000001100000';
var nro-reemplazante = '2';             |    $nro-reemplazante = '2';
var posicion = '3';                     |    $posicion = '3';
```

Estas son mis variables, quiero poder reemplazar el tercer carácter de mi variable `elstring` el cual es el numero 1 y cambiarlo por el número 2 dejando mi variable `elstring` como `'1021000001100000'`

intente hacerlo en PHP con `substr_replace` de la siguiente forma `substr_replace($elstring ,$nro-reemplazante,$posicion)` pero no me funciona porque si bien es cierto me reemplaza en la posición de caracter indicada pero ya no escribe lo demás por ejemplo :

```
              PHP
$elstring = '1011000001100000';
$nro-reemplazante = '3';
$posicion = '6';

echo substr_replace($elstring ,$nro-reemplazante,$posicion)
```

Me imprime : 101103 , reemplaza el carácter en la posición correcta, pero ya no imprime el resto del string, si me dan consejos de como solucionarlo en PHP o en JS me seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PHP

Realmente cuando programamos hay que pensar en los posibles errores. Supongamos que la cadena tiene `16` caracteres, y por error el usuario requiere un reemplazo en la posición `17` ... ¿qué arrojaría un código con `substr_replace` en ese caso? Vamos a verlo:

```
$str = '1011000001100000';
$char = '3';
$pos = '17';
echo substr_replace($str ,$char,$pos,1);
```

**Salida:**

```
10110000011000003
```

Le hemos pedido que reemplace el carácter que hay en la posición `17` por un `3`, dado que no hay posición `17`, lo que hace `substr_replace` es agregar un `3` en dicha posición. **Esa no es la finalidad de la función, por lo tanto este problema no lo podemos resolver mediante `substr_replace`**.

Esto lo podemos resolver por una función personalizada en la cual vamos a tratar la cadena como lo que es, un array. Buscaremos si la posición requerida existe en la cadena y haremos el reemplazo. Si no existe, levantaremos una excepción (o podemos retornar `FALSE` también o un mensaje u otra cosa.

Veamos:

```
function replaceAt($str, $char, $pos) {
    /*Dado que el índice comienza en 0*/
    $pos=$pos-1;
    if ( ! isset($str[$pos])) {
       //return FALSE;
       throw new Exception('Posición de reemplazo mayor que el tamaño de la cadena');
   }
   $str[$pos] = $char;
   return $str;
}
```

Probemos con los datos erróneos de más arriba:

```
echo replaceAt($str,$char,$pos);
```

**Salida:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Posición de reemplazo mayor que
>   el tamaño de la cadena in source_file.php:28 Stack trace:
>
> 0 source_file.php(8): replaceAt('101100000110000...', '*', 16)
>
> 1 {main}   thrown in source_file.php on line 28

Como hemos visto, el error fue detectado.

Probemos ahora con datos correctos:

```
$str = '1011000001100000';
$char = '2';
$pos = '6';
echo replaceAt($str,$char,$pos);
```

**Salida:**

```
1011020001100000
     *
```

A nuestra función `replaceAt` la podemos dotar todavía de otro tipo de controles, por ejemplo, hacerla *nullsafe* (si queremos) para que controle situaciones como esta por ejemplo:

```
$str = '1011000001100000';
$char = NULL;
$pos = '6';
echo replaceAt($str,$char,$pos);
```

---

### Javascript

Podemos hacer una función parecida. Partiremos de `String.prototype`para poder devolver la misma cadena modificada. El código se basa en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/5587982), pero controla que la posición solicitada no exceda el tamaño de la cadena, en cuyo caso devolverá `false` (puedes también levantar un Error o Excepción, como hicimos en PHP).

He aquí un código de prueba.

```js
var str = '1011000001100000';
var char = '2';
var pos = '6';

/*Función*/
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
  index = parseInt(index) - 1;
  if (typeof this[index] === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }

  return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

/*PRUEBAS: */
/*a. Correcto*/
console.log(str.replaceAt(pos, char));

/*b. Incorrecto*/
console.log(str.replaceAt(77, char));
```

Ambas funciones son ciertamente mejorables, todo dependerá del alcance que le quieras dar. Lo cierto es que cuando programamos, hay que tomar en cuenta que el usuario puede introducir datos incorrectos, por lo que nuestro código debe preveer algunos controles mínimos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme la manera correcta de aplicar estas funciones, de verdad te agradezco la explicación detallada, por aportaciones como la tuya esta comunidad es grande ;)

Answer (score 3):

En el caso de PHP, esta la firma del metodo:
substr_replace ( mixed $string , mixed $replacement , mixed $start [, mixed $length ] )

Te falta especificar un parametro mas (LA LONGITUD O LENGTH), es decir cuantos caracteres reemplazaras iniciando desde $posicion, en este caso el length sera solo 1, y si lo omites digamos que el reemplazo se "come" toda la cadena iniciando desde $posicion:

```
substr_replace($elstring ,$nro-reemplazante,$posicion,1)
```

Por ejemplo si quieres reemplazar 4 caracteres:

```
substr_replace($elstring ,$nro-reemplazante,$posicion,4)
```

Esto te dara 1011003100000

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente esta es la solución, gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Con JS:**

```js
const replaceAt = (string, index, replace) => {
  return string.substring(0, index) + replace + string.substring(index + 1);
}

var string = '1011000001100000';     
var replace = '2';             
var index = 3;   

console.log(replaceAt(string,index,replace))
```

**con PHP:**

```
function replaceAt($string, $index, $replace){

  return substr_replace($string,$replace,$index,1) 

}

$string = '1011000001100000';     
$replace = '2';             
$index = 3;  

echo replaceAt($string, $index, $replace);
```

Comment: Efectivamente esta seria la solución, muchas gracias :)